# Order bank movements by date and balance left

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table that holds bank movements, I'm importing those movements from csv and json files, each movement has an amount and a balance next to it.

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cuenta_banco_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| referencia       | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| monto            | decimal(10,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| saldo            | decimal(10,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type             | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id          | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fecha_movimiento | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.08 sec)

{
    "Date": "22/04/2019",
    "Operation": "MC",
    "Reference": "15",
    "Description": "TRANSF. VIA INTERNET          ",
    "Amount": "10000.00",
    "Balance": "1869255.04"
  }
```

The file is being imported entirely into the database, the thing is that I need to sort it correctly when displaying the data

I need to display the movements in descending order by date but also that the balance is correcly displayed.

An example of what I need:

[image]

And this is how I get the movements:

```
+------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | cuenta_banco_id | referencia  | monto      | saldo     | type | user_id | fecha_movimiento    | created_at          | updated_at          |
+------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3367 |               4 | 2297353555  |   10000.00 | 665445.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
| 3366 |               4 | 2297322435  |   11000.00 | 655445.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
| 3398 |               4 | 2297751229  |   11000.00 | 651695.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:34 | 2019-04-20 18:15:34 |
| 3362 |               4 | 2297311718  |   12000.00 | 651445.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
| 3343 |               4 | 2296877327  |   10000.00 | 649845.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
| 3365 |               4 | 2297317974  | -525000.00 | 644445.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
| 3431 |               4 | 2298293430  |   13000.00 | 643195.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:35 | 2019-04-20 18:15:35 |
| 3397 |               4 | 2297748073  |   15900.00 | 640695.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:34 | 2019-04-20 18:15:34 |
| 3342 |               4 | 2296823905  |   30000.00 | 639845.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
| 3361 |               4 | 64665863950 |  500000.00 | 639445.90 |    0 |       1 | 2019-04-20 23:59:59 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 | 2019-04-20 18:15:33 |
+------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The field cuenta_banco_id identifies the bank that owns the movements but there's no relation between the movements of different banks.

This is on Laravel 5.7, and MySQL 5.7.23 the query I'm using is:

```
$movimientos = Movimiento::query();
$movimientos->where('cuenta_banco_id', $request->banco);
$movimientos->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(fecha_movimiento)'), [$start->startOfDay()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $end->endOfDay()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
$movimientos->with('recargas', 'banks', 'recargas.transactions', 'movimientos_detalles', 'recargas.transactions.siteuser');
$movimientos->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
$movimientos = $movimientos->paginate(50);
```

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: the pictures are not clear. Could you please add text to define your output and expected output instead of images?

Comment: @sabharikarthik I sure do, give me a minute

Comment: @sabharikarthik apologies but I couldn't copy it from the bank website. I added a different screenshot

Comment: @sabharikarthik also added the current output from sql

Comment: Thank you. I have added an answer. Try that and let us know if that works for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, your transactions are purely ordered based on time (i.e., transaction_date DESC and then created_time ASC). And since you are using a where clause on Bank ID, we are looking at the transactions of only a single bank here (I am not clear on whether it covers the transaction of all users. If so, we need to partition by users before applying order by). Assuming, 'fecha_movimiento' captures the date of transaction and 'id' captures the order of transaction, you can try something like this:

```
$movimientos->orderBy(DB::raw('date(fecha_movimiento)'), 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('id','ASC');
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to partially work. The thing is that in the movements there are outgoing transfers to other accounts so Balance can be 1.000.000 and next 300.000, that's what is breaking my head.

Comment: Also how can I calculate the current balance in the account? I've tried using sum because I have positive and negatives values but the result differs a lot from the actual balance on the account.

Comment: oo...okay...Is this the table of all transactions from any account to any other account? If so, can you add the above mentioned case as well to the input and expected output part. Because, that will convey more clearly than convo on comments. And, for the balance part, you can use SUM(CASE...), but leave that for now. Let us wrap this up first.

Comment: Haha sure I'm adding it right now, thanks for the assist.

Comment: Sorry edited again because the last edit showed wrong balance format.

Comment: looks like your actual output is covering more cases (having negative transacts on monto) than expected output. If you could replicate the same data on the expected output part, that will be great.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna add the expected output

Comment: Can you add your mysql version as well??

Comment: Done, added the expected output with the negative values and the mysql version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192160/discussion-between-sabhari-karthik-and-douglas-roos).